# Highlight word in DT in shiny based on regex

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Using DT in shiny, I want to be able to highlight the selected word. Setting `searchHighlight = TRUE` is close to what I want, but this will also highlight words that include the search. For example, if I am searching for "on" it will also match "stone", highlighting the "on" in the middle.

EXAMPLE IMAGE:

[image: Words within words being highlighted]

I can refine the search options so `regex = TRUE`, but then no highlighting occurs. This is also true if I want to use regex like "on|in", for example.

EXAMPLE (including regex):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

example_data <- data.table(words = c("on", "scone", "wrong", "stone"), 
                           description = c("The word on", "Scone is not on.", "Not on either", "Not here at all"))

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("word_select", label = "Word to search")
      ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("word_searched")
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$word_searched <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      example_data, 
      options = list(searchHighlight = TRUE, 
                     search = list(regex = TRUE, 
                                   search = paste0("\\b", tolower(input$word_select), "\\b")))
    )
  })

  })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The DT is already being filtered on the word by a reactive expression, so all the fields will definitely include the selected word, but I just want to avoid confusion from users thinking that longer words are being included in the search erroneously. I haven't done this in the example but just confirming this is not the element I'm concerned about.

Thanks for your help.

(EDITED to add an example of a word with punctuation in the example data.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of relying on datatable's search functionality you can create a `reactive` element that first filters by the input, and then replaces the matching words with the same word embedded in a `<span style="background-color:yellow;">` tag. This should allow more search flexibility via more complex regex.

You'll need to add `escape = F` to `datatable` so the HTML tag is interpreted properly. I've added `options = list(dom = "lt")` to `datatable` to remove the datatable's search field and direct attention to the left search field.

The filtering criteria are left fairly fuzzy to keep the table from disappearing until a perfect match is found – i.e. the table shouldn't disappear when you type "o" because there's no perfect match, and then reappear at "on". The highlights then only appear if a matching word is found, i.e. `on`, `On`, and `on.`, but not `stone`, `scone`, etc. Here's a glimpse of what it looks like:

[image]

And here's the code. Note that I use dplyr's filtering and mutating functions because they can easily be applied to multiple columns via their `*_all` variants:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr) # For `filter_all` and `mutate_all`.

example_data <- iris
    # data.table(words = c("on", "scone", "wrong", "stone"), 
    #                        description = c("The word on", "Scone is not on.", "Not on either", "Not here at all"))

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput("word_select", label = "Word to search")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            dataTableOutput("word_searched")
        )
    )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    # This is your reactive element.
    df_reactive <- reactive({
            example_data %>%
                # Filter if input is anywhere, even in other words.
                filter_all(any_vars(grepl(input$word_select, ., T, T))) %>% 
                # Replace complete words with same in HTML.
                mutate_all(~ gsub(
                              paste(c("\\b(", input$word_select, ")\\b"), collapse = ""),
                              "<span style='background-color:yellow;'>\\1</span>",
                              .,
                              TRUE,
                              TRUE
                              )
                          )
    })

    # Render your reactive element here.
    output$word_searched <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(df_reactive(), escape = F, options = list(dom = "lt"))
    })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, this basically works! It doesn't necessarily work for the regex element but I think I can work out something for that with this approach. NB I used the following code for the reactive to keep using data.table (doesn't filter because I didn't need that but similar approaches are possible): `example_data_dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub(
      paste0("\\b(", input$word_select, ")\\b"),
      "<span style='background-color:yellow;'>\\1</span>",
      x,
      TRUE,
      TRUE
    ))]`

Comment: I really appreciate that this looks at the problem from a different angle to how I was trying to do it (from within DT itself) :)

Comment: @Megan happy to hear it works! This strategy also has the advantage that there are fewer constraints on what you can do. For example, using if-else conditions you could use one color for partial matches and another for full matches, etc. I might be mistaken, but datatable's built-in search highlighting doesn't look very versatile.

Comment: @gersht thanks a lot for this regex, it's really useful! I've slightly adapted your code to make it work just with one column of my dataset: `mutate(caption = gsub(pattern = paste(c("\\b(", input$filter_captions, ")\\b"),  collapse = ""), replacement  = "<span style='background-color: #F08080;'>\\1</span>", x = data_insta_filtered$caption))`.
However, I have a question: do you know how I can highlight not just the entire word, but just a small part of a word that matches with my selection? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is what you exactly want but this is close I think: this does not perform an exact search (e.g. "on" will match "stone") but *this only highlights the exact match* (e.g. "on" will not be highlighted). This uses the `mark.js` library.

```
dtable <- datatable(iris[c(1,2,51,52,101,102),], 
                    options = list(
                      mark = list(accuracy = "exactly")
                    )
)
dep1 <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "datatables.mark", "2.0.1", 
  src = c(href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/features/mark.js"),
  script = "datatables.mark.min.js")
dep2 <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "jquery.mark", "8.11.1", 
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1"), 
  script = "jquery.mark.min.js")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep1, dep2))
dtable
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. I've checked this within the shiny app and it almost works. One thing I've noticed is that it won't highlight words with punctuation - for example if the word is something like "(on)" or at the end of a sentence like "on." Do you know any way to deal with that? Separately (and less importantly) is there a way to change the highlight colour? Mine is a very pale yellow on the screen that isn't bright enough to really stand out.

Comment: @Megan See the doc [here](https://markjs.io/). You can control the colour with CSS. For the punctuation I don't know.